# Error: 424 - Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.ResponseText)

Tags: excel

The goal is to query URL on a periodic to display currenccy values for a given currency.

```
Error 424 observed at the line: Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.ResponseText)
```

full VBA:

```
Private Sub GetCurrencyValues()
    Dim http As Object
    Dim json As Object
    Dim rate As Double
    Dim curr As String
    
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    curr = "USD" ' US Dollar
    http.Open "GET", "https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/" & curr, False
    http.Send
    
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.ResponseText)
    
    rate = json("rates")("JPY") ' Japanese Yen
    Range("A1").Value = rate
    
    rate = json("rates")("GBP") ' British Pound
    Range("B1").Value = rate
    
    rate = json("rates")("NOK") ' Norwegian Kroner
    Range("C1").Value = rate
    
    rate = json("rates")("MXN") ' Mexican Peso
    Range("D1").Value = rate
    
    rate = json("rates")("EUR") ' Euro
    Range("E1").Value = rate
    
    rate = json("rates")("PLN") ' Polish Zloty
    Range("F1").Value = rate
End Sub

Private Sub StartTimer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "GetCurrencyValues"
End Sub
```

Where do I install the JSON library in order to parse the JSON response from the API?

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps:
Download the JsonConverter library from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases.
Extract it and in VB editor select Tools > References.
Download the latest release
Import JsonConverter.bas into your project (Open VBA Editor, Alt + F11; File > Import File)
Add Dictionary reference/class
For Windows-only, include a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
In the References dialog box, make sure that "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and "Microsoft XML, v6.0" are also checked.
Click OK to close the References dialog box.